# c++ implicit pointer conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, implicit

I have the following test program (demonstrates what I am really trying to accomplish).

Does anyone know if the following is possible without a reinterpret_cast<>?

```
struct B;

struct A {
  A() { }
  A( const B &b) { }
  A( const B *b) { }
  A( B *b) { }

  A* operator=(const B *b) { }
  A* operator=(B *b) { }
};

struct B {
  B() { }
  B( const A &a) { }
  B( const B * b) { }
  B( B *b) { }

  B* operator=(const A *a) { }
  B* operator=(A *a) { }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  A *a = new A();
  B *b = new B();

  A *c = b;

  return 0;
}
```

I tried doing every conversion operator I could, but I just can't seem to get

```
  A *c = b;
```

to not complain

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'B *' to 'A *'
```

Comment: You could make `B` *inherit* from `A`. Otherwise the pointer conversion doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: It is a contrived example, but in the production code I am working on A and B are convertible via conversion constructors (via reference)

Comment: But they're entirely different types. Treating one *as if* it was the other makes no sense.

Comment: A **cast** is something you write in your source code; it tells the compiler to do a **conversion**. Because it goes in the source code, there is no such thing as an **implicit cast**. There is, however, such a things as an **implicit conversion**.

Comment: You can do it by references. References can be converted implicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible, because a `B` is not an `A`.  You either need to use inheritance to make `B` a subclass of `A` (so that a `B` is an `A`), or use composition and then refer to the appropriate subobject.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to make that line not be an error, because in your example `B*` and `A*` are not implicitly convertible.

They would be, if they were in the same inheritance hierarchy in the correct order, or if `A` was a typedef for `void`. Now the types are unrelated, and the language rules deny implicit conversions between such unrelated pointer types.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers can not be cast. Even if there are defined the operator= function. That works only on the respective objects, not on their pointer.

like that:

```
A *c;
*c = b;  //or 
c->operator=(b);
```